# 404 Error Python Django

Tags: python, django, url

Esse é o erro que eu estou tendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem ver na lista de URLS o numero 8 é igual ao "current url" informado abaixo.

Minha lista de url:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from principal.views import IndexView, LogOut, RedirQuiz

urlpatterns = [
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),    
    url(r'^$', IndexView),
    url(r'^sair/$', LogOut),
    url(r'^Quiz/$', RedirQuiz),
]
```

Minha view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.template import loader

def IndexView(request):
    template = 'index.html'
    return render(request, template)



def LogOut(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')



def RedirQuiz(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render('Quizz.html')
    return HttpResponse(request(render))
```

O que eu quero fazer é simplesmente redirecionar uma página após a autenticação de usuário. No entanto, mesmo criando o arquivo em HTML pra me referir, ele saber onde esta o arquivo, usar o link correto, obtenho esse erro.

Comment: Você está no StackOverflow **em Português**, se não traduzir sua pergunta, ela será fechada. | You're in StackOverflow **in Portuguese**, if you don't translate your question, it'll be closed.

Comment: Traduzido......

Answer (score 4):

Troque

```
 url(r'^Quiz/$', RedirQuiz),
```

por

```
 url(r'Quiz/$', RedirQuiz),
```

Ou

```
url(r'complete/facebook/Quiz/?$),
```

Os caracteres `^` e `$` são especiais.

O primeiro(^) diz que a combinação deve INICIAR e o segundo($) deve TERMINAR.